# Dynamically added input's value not being captured in Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a form where I add input fields dynamically using a jquery and then submitting the values of that form  using Laravel Php

My html:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="mytext[]">
  </div>
</div>
```

My script:

```
<script type="">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
  })
});
</script>
```

The problem is that when I submit the values I've entered in the input boxes and try to capture them using the following Laravel code.

```
$mytext =Request::get('mytext');
dd($mytext);
```

Only the first value of the input I've defined in the html is captured no matter how many text inputs I add.

The output:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "Text box 1"
]
```

How do I solve this? Thanks

Comment: You need to have different name tags in order for it to work, what you could do is change the loop so it makes the name tags unique by appending the count to the name attr like so `name="mytext' + count + "`

Comment: @GerritLuimstra - is that a Laravel thing? PHP will properly handle inputs named in "array" convention. You could have many inputs named `text[]`, and the `$_POST['text']` value would be a numerically indexed array of the inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add different name for the each input you add.

**Your HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="mytext[text]">
```

**Your JS:**

```
var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[text'+  x++  +']"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
       }
});
```

**The output will be:**

```
"mytext" => array:4 [▼
   "text" => "Text"
   "text1" => "Text1"
   "text2" => "Text2"
   "text3" => "Text3"
]
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

You already have a variable to count the appended inputs...
Use it!

Notice `name="mytext'+x+'"`:

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext'+x+'"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
```

And also sent the `x` to know how many are sent.